# Why does calling transpose in my data switch the row's index from a MultiIndex to a flat Index?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV that looks like this:

```
name,location,sales,customer_count
john,fairfax,1000,400
jane,daly city,500,350
john,springfield,800,240
john,richmond,200,80
jane,san jose,300,90
george,albany,200,60
john,centreville,600,150
```

I iterate through each row 3 records at a time:

```
reader = pd.read_csv(input_csv_path, chunksize=3)

for row in reader:
```

I create a `pivot_table` and print out its index:

```
pivot_table_row = row.pivot_table(index=['name', 'location'])
print(pivot_table_row.index)

MultiIndex(levels=[[u'jane', u'john'], [u'daly city', u'fairfax', u'springfield']],
           codes=[[0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2]],
           names=[u'name', u'location'])
```

Since tranposition turns rows into columns and vice-versa, I would expect the *new* index to be named `jane`, `john`, `daly city`, and `fairfax`, with `levels=['name', 'location']`. That does not appear to be the case:

```
    transposed_pivot_table_row = pivot_table_row.T
    print(transposed_pivot_table_row.index)

Index([u'customer_count', u'sales'], dtype='object')
```

Why does the index change from a `MultiIndex` of `['name', 'location]` to a flat `Index` of `['customer_count', 'sales']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original `MultiIndex` *in its entirety* becomes the columns. The *remaining* columns from *before* the transpose (`customer_count`, `sales`) become the *new* index, with no names.

You'll see this when you inspect the `pivot_table_row.index.names` and `pivot_table_row.columns.names` properties:

```
    pivot_table_row = df.pivot_table(index=['name', 'location'])
    print(pivot_table_row.index.names)
    ['name', 'location']

    print(pivot_table_row.columns.names)
    [None]

    pivot_table_row = df.pivot_table(index=['name', 'location']).T
    print(pivot_table_row.index.names)
    [None]

    print(pivot_table_row.columns.names)
    ['name', 'location']
```

As you can see, the original columns had no names to begin with. Once transposition takes place, the columns become the index, and thus has no names. So in your example, the remaining columns `customer_count` and `sales` jointly form the new index, without names.

Comment: While that shows the index names becoming column names, it doesn't answer why the old `MultiIndex` became a flat `Index`. Why were the levels a certain way to begin with? Why do I no longer have levels in the index after the tranposition?

Comment: @CJVirtucio - Because columns are changed do index. So if MultiIndex in index, then after transpose multiindex in columns

Comment: @CJVirtucio - And if column without MultiIndex in columns then after transpose get no MultiIndex in index

Comment: Ok, I think I have an idea of what you're trying to say. So the original `MultiIndex` _in its entirety_ becomes the columns. The _remaining_ columns from before the transpose (`customer_count`, `sales`) become the _new_ index, with _no names_. Is that correct?

Comment: @CJVirtucio - Exactly ;)

Comment: !@CJVirtucio - Thank you.